# Create multiple objects simultaneously using for loop in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Word model with one column: word. I have a form that creates an @word object when submitted.

words/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@word, :remote => (params[:action] == 'new' ? true : false)) do |f| %>
  <fieldset>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.text_field :word, :required => true %>
    </div>
  </fieldset>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit :disable_with => 'Submitting...' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

words/create.js.erb

```
$('#words').prepend( '<%= escape_javascript(render @word) %>' );
$('#new-word-form-container').find('input:not(:submit),select,textarea').val('');
```

I'd like to shorthand the creation of multiple words simontaniously on one form submission (i.e. instead of having to resubmit to create each individual word).

I have a method in my Word model that splits the string into an array of words (separated by a comma or space).

```
class Word < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessible :word

  # Split Words method splits words seperated by a comma or space
  def self.split_words(word)
    # Determine if multiple words
    if word.match(/[\s,]+/)
      word = word.split(/[\s,]+/)    # Split and return array of words
    else 
      word = word.split              # String => array 
    end 
  end

end
```

I'm trying to use a for loop within my `create` action to step through each array element, and create an @word object for the element.

```
class WordsController < ApplicationController
respond_to :js, :json, :html

def create
  split = Word.split_words(params[:word])

  split.each do |w|
    @word = Word.create(params[:w])
    respond_with(@word)
  end
end
```

I'm currently getting a HashWithIndifferentAccess error, as listed below.

```
Started POST "/words" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-10 13:09:26 -0400
    Processing by WordsController#create as JS
      Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"0hOmyrQfFWHRkBt8hYs7zKuHjCwYhYdv444Zl+GWzEA=", "word"=>{"word"=>"stack, overflow"}, "commit"=>"Create Word"}
    Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 0ms

    NoMethodError (undefined method `match' for {"word"=>"stack, overflow"}:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess):
      app/models/word.rb:9:in `split_words'
      app/controllers/words_controller.rb:36:in `create'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your form.

Comment: Im thinking the match method isn't available for the ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess object, can you convert the word object to a standard ruby hash object before the conditional? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html

Comment: Yeah just tried it in console, you could do something like w = word.to_hash, if w.match...

Comment: Still getting the error.. I've also tried putting the conditional directly in the controller action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `create` action in the words controller, you fetch the words from the `params` which gives you back a `parameter` object. The `parameter` object is a `hash` like object that inherits from `ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess`. Then you try and call the `match` method on your `parameter` object and it does not know how to respond to it, so you get a `NoMethodError`.

Checkout http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html

The first thing you need to do is pass `params[:word][:word]` instead of `params[:word]`, this should give you back a `string` object and this method should now work.

It also looks like you might run into another problem in the `each` loop in `create` as `params[:w]` might return `nil`. You should instead just pass in `w` because that will be each word in the `array` you are iterating over and if am not mistaken you want to create a `word` object for each word.

```
def create
 split = Word.split_words(params[:word][:word])

 @words = split.map do |w|
   Word.create(word: w)
 end

 respond_with(@words)
end
```

Comment: When using the query "stack", This causes a NoMethodError (undefined method `stringify_keys' for "stack":String):

Comment: On which line Kyle.Belanger? Could you also tell me what  `params[word][word]` returns. For this `{"word"=>"stack, overflow"}` I was expecting it to return "stack, overflow".

Answer (score 0):

```
class WordsController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :js, :json, :html

  def create
    @words = params[:word].split.map { |word| Word.create(word) }
    respond_with(@words)
  end
end
```

Comment: This answer was flagged for deletion but I'm not going to delete it.  However, a few words around your solution will massively improve the answer and also help the OP understand how this solves their problem.

Comment: I agree with @RoboticCat. However, this still returns a HashWithIndifferentAccess error regardless.